# How to print out two columns per line, formatted

Tags: python, output-formatting

I have two files with 2 columns each, I need to use 1 column from one and one from another and create a new file with 2 columns.

```
while i<500020:
    columns=datas.readline()
    columns2 = datas2.readline()
    columns = columns.split("  ")
    columns2 = columns2.split("    ")
    colum.write(" {1}   {0}".format((columns2[1]), (columns[1]) ))
    i=i+1
```

My output is like this:

```
 181.053131
  0.0005301
 168.785828
  0.3596852
```

I want to show them on same line, EX:

```
 181.053131     0.0005301
 168.785828     0.3596852
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the newline from `columns2[1]`:

```
columns2 = datas.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

otherwise you'll always insert those newlines into your output.

I'd also remove the newline from `columns` and use an explicit newline when writing:

```
columns = datas.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

and

```
colum.write(" {1}   {0}\n".format(columns2[1], columns[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly